# Send CoreData array to remote with Alamofire Post in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I want to, Send `CoreData` array to remote with `Alamofire` `Post`  , I have core data `Entity`, schema under below;

```
MyPlace

- longitude (double)
- latitude (double)
- altitude (double)
- date (date)
```

My codes;

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"MyPlace")

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    do {
        let lokas = try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [MyPlace]
        if lokas.count > 1 {

            let prod: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
            let prodArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

            for i in 0 ..< lokas.count {
                let a = lokas[i]
                prod.setValue(a.longitude, forKey: "longitude")
                prod.setValue(a.latitude, forKey: "latitude")
                prod.setValue(a.altitude, forKey: "altitude")
                prod.setValue(a.date, forKey: "date")
                prodArray.add(prod)
            }

            let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                "Accept": "text/html",
                "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ]

            Alamofire.request(PostUrl, method: .post, parameters: prodArray, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
                .responseData{ response in
                    let json = JSON(data:response.result.value!)
                    let success = json["result"]["status"].boolValue

                    if success == true {
                    }

          }

        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```

Also my prodArray output under below;

```
(
        {
        longitude = "-0.1337";
        latitude = "51.50998";
        altitude = 0;
        date = "2017-02-01 08:47:20 +0000";
    },
        {
        longitude = "-0.1337";
        latitude = "51.50998";
        altitude = 0;
        date = "2017-02-01 08:47:20 +0000";
    },
        {
        longitude = "-0.1337";
        latitude = "51.50998";
        altitude = 0;
        date = "2017-02-01 08:47:20 +0000";
    },
        {
        longitude = "-0.1337";
        latitude = "51.50998";
        altitude = 0;
        date = "2017-02-01 08:47:20 +0000";
    }
)
```

Giving error line;

```
Alamofire.request(PostUrl, method: .post, parameters: prodArray, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
```

Error;

> Extra argument 'method' in call. in .post

I think array wrong. or else ?

Comment: Alamofire.request(PostUrl, method: .post, parameters: prodArray, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers) replace this line with  

Alamofire.request(PostUrl, method: .post, parameters: prodArray [0], encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya same error

Comment: Alamofire.request(urlString,method: .post, parameters: requestParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]) try this one and ya print prodArray before alamofire execution .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya same error